# Loops in Access VBA

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

I'm kind of new to Access VBA and I’m having issues with my loop.

I have reviewed various books, websites, asked various friends. Currently I’m trying to have a user input two characters, and then if the two characters equal a certain combination then it is supposed to equal a numeric value, and then use the value in a distance calculation.

The user inputed values are strings and everything else is declared as double.

I have 200+ combinations that I am testing and have tried `case` statements, `DLookup`, `do while`, `do until`, `if`, and `elseif` loops with no success.

I'm also limited by IT and I’m unable to use DAO code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest creating a table to formally define the various character combinations and the corresponding value for each combination. This has the advantage that the combinations may be easily maintained going forward, rather than defining such combinations as part of queries or in VBA code.

Such a table could be as simple as containing three fields:

- Character 1 (Text)
- Character 2 (Text)
- Value (Number)

[image]

You could then populate such a table with your valid combinations:

[image]

With the combinations rigorously defined, you have many options regarding how to prompt the user to enter the two characters and obtain the correponding value.

A very simplistic approach might be to use a form with three textboxes:

[image]

Here, the first two textboxes would be unbound, and might be called `char1` and `char2`, and the third textbox might be called `result` and have a **Control Source** property equal to:

```
=DLookup("Value", "LookupTable", "char1 = '" & [char1] & "' and char2 = '" & [char2] & "'")
```

This would yield the following behaviour:

[image]

Comment: and you not using any DAO recordsets either! (I think that was a attempt to tie your hands, and using dlookup() in place of a DAO reocrdset is most excellent on your part!

Comment: Hi Lee. Thank you for everything! I’m having a slight problem though. I typed everything in just like you said Yoda, but it isn’t working for some reason. I’m getting an error of #Name? Do you have any advice on how to fix it? Thank you again for all of your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @Divingmickey You're welcome. I assume that the `#Name` appears in the result textbox? If so, are the other two textboxes named `char1` and `char2`?

Comment: Yes, the #Name? Error is in the text box. I have char1  = StartNode and char2 = EndNode, both are strings. Time is double like the rest of my wonderful numbers and my table is named NODES. What am I doing wrong Yoda?

Comment: Are your fields named `StartNode` & `EndNode` or your textboxes? Or both? Have you changed all elements of the `DLookup` expression appropriately, including the `Value` field name?

Comment: My fields are named start and endnode. My value field is called time

Comment: `start` and `endnode` OR `startnode` and `endnode`? Have you named your textboxes the same as your fields, per my example? Have you changed the field, table & textbox names in my `DLookup` example to suit your field & table names?

Comment: Good morning Lee (Yoda). I went back through everything to make sure that everything was labeled correctly. I missed one box. That got rid of the error, but it is still not giving me the numerical value for “Time “. I’m going to go back and triple check my code. Thank you very much for all of your assistance with this.  I hope that you have a great day.

Comment: Hello Yoda. I went through everything and I’m not sure why I am not getting the values.

Comment: @Divingmickey To ensure that you understand what's going on, I would suggest going back to basics: create a new database in Access and recreate the tables & form in my above example until you have it working, then you'll hopefully understand how everything is working and what is going wrong in your own database.

Comment: Hello Lee. I tried that and also tried starting a brand new session with in access, tried using combo boxes, text boxes, a combination of different boxes, and various different loops - nothing worked. I’m still having issues with my output. Thank you for your continued assistance

Comment: @Divingmickey Are you saying that, having created a new table per my table, with fields named as per my example, and populated with data as per my example, and with a form created with three textboxes named per my example, and with the control source for the result set per my example, that you don't receive the result that I demonstrate in my animation?

Comment: Yes. I believe that my hands are tied by my IT department. Unfortunately. I really liked your straightforward solution too. It works great at the house, just not at work unfortunately. We are also barred from creating and using macros in Excel. I’m getting away with some stuff in Access as it’s not widely used as much as Excel. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Access as a database and GUI application by storing your 200+ combinations in a table with corresponding numeric value. Then have an SQL query filter by user input and use resulting value for needed calculations. Below requires creating and using four [Access objects](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/database-basics-a849ac16-07c7-4a31-9948-3c8c94a7c204): table, query, form, and module.

**Table** *(tblCombinations)*

```
 id  combn1  combn2  numeric_value
  1       A       B            150  
  2       C       D            225
  3       E       F            100 
  4       G       H             75
  5       I       J            200
...
```

**SQL** *(no loops needed; using Access form control values)*

```sql
SELECT c.combn1, c.combn2, c.numeric_value
FROM tblCombinations c
WHERE c.combn1 = Forms!myForm!myUserInputField1
  AND c.combn2 = Forms!myForm!myUserInputField2
```

And even pass needed numeric value in distance calculation formula which can be a VBA function in a standard module:

```sql
SELECT c.combn1, c.combn2, Distance_Calculation(c.numeric_value) As distance_result
FROM tblCombinations c
WHERE c.combn1 = Forms!myForm!myUserInputField1
  AND c.combn2 = Forms!myForm!myUserInputField2
```

**VBA** *(place in standard module)*

```vb
Public Function Distance_Calculation(num_value As Long) As Double
   ...
   Distance_Calculation = some_value 
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you all for all of your assistance. This has been driving me batty and turning my hair grey. Unfortunately, I’m still having issues getting the numerical results. I guess I will be dying my hair this weekend

Answer (score 0):

You can use following type function in your result form button or after event on both textboxes-
       Dim resultValue as Integer
       If DCount("numeric_value", "tblCombinations", "[combn1] = '" & Forms!myForm!myUserInputField1 & "' and [combn2] = '" & Forms!myForm!myUserInputField2 & "'") > 0 then

```
  resultValue = Dlookup("numeric_value", "tblCombinations", "[combn1] = '" & Forms!myForm!myUserInputField1 & "' and [combn2] = '" & Forms!myForm!myUserInputField2 & "'")

   txtResult = Distance_Calculation(resultValue)
```

Else
       Msgbox "No such combination exist. Kindly check combimation", vbinformation, "Information"

```
  txtResult = 0
```

End if